# Show SharePoint 2013 Calendar Views Individually in Outlook

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar

I have one main calendar where I made different views (vacation, on-call, training) and then I put each view on the main calendar as an overlay.

I know that you cannot show the overlays in Outlook. Is there a way to connect **each calendar view** individually as their own calendar in Outlook?

Note: They are not set up as individual calendars in SP, they are set up as individual views.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook imports the default calendar fields or columns as Outlook controls creating, viewing and editing the items. The SharePoint views you create are only available in the web browser. Also the additional columns you add to the calendar will not appear in Outlook. I can't recall the category column appearing in Outlook